# C3872 MFC String conversion

Tags: c++, mfc

given the following code:

```
CA2T strñ("ñ");
CA2T strñ("Ñ");
```

Not sure why it doesn't compile for that character but works with:

```
CA2T stradiaeresis("Ä");
CA2T strodiaeresis("Ö");
CA2T strudiaeresis("Ü");
```

**[Error    C3872](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c3872)   '0xb1': this character is not allowed in an identifier**

Any way around this?

Comment: `strñ` it's the `ñ` in the identifier it doesn't like.  For a complete definition see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers  And Windows is UTF-16, so __if__ you UTF-8 source files it can get really upset.

Comment: Also, you can't have two variables with the same name in the same scope.

Comment: @RichardCritten: Source code does not interact with the OS. It is digested by a compiler, and Visual Studio will happily read UTF-8 encoded source files.

Comment: You already posted a link to an explanation, including the solution. Why did you decide against reading it?

Comment: @IInspectable Maybe because I need to use it and the solution is to not use it because it's out of range?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the [error message C3872](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c3872), you are using an illegal character in the identifier `strñ`. The range of legal characters is documented under the topic [Identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/identifiers-cpp).

To make the code compile, you're going to have to use legal identifier names, e.g.

```
CA2T str_latin_small_letter_n_with_tilde("ñ");
CA2T str_latin_capital_letter_n_with_tilde("Ñ");
```

While that makes the code compile, there are several issues, that need to be addressed:

- The `CA2T` [conversion macro](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3.aspx) indicates ANSI (codepage) encoding for its source type. Using ANSI encoding is typically undesirable.
- The `CA2T` conversion macro specifies a `TCHAR` as its destination type. This is *never* useful today. The [generic-text mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/generic-text-mappings) stopped being useful, when Windows 98 was released.
- The [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) uses ANSI encoding. Again, ANSI encoding is undesirable, for being limited as well as potentially changing its meaning when moving to a compiler running in a different locale.

If surprises are low on your wish list, consider changing the code to the following:

```
CStringW str_latin_small_letter_n_with_tilde(L"ñ");
CStringW str_latin_capital_letter_n_with_tilde(L"Ñ");
```

Doing so explicitly requests Unicode character encodings (UTF-16 LE in case of Visual Studio). This is in the vast majority of cases, what you want.

Comment: Interesting. When I have been workign with the `tinyxml2` library I have always done this as it is the only think I got to work: `LPCTSTR szAssistant = CA2CT(pAttrAssistant->Value(), CP_UTF8);`

Comment: @AndrewTruckle: That should really be `LPCWSTR` and `CA2CW`, i.e. it should not rely on the generic-text mappings. The snippet you posted also doesn't rely on ANSI encoding. It specifically names the source character encoding, and using UTF-8 is unambiguous, unlike ANSI encoding. Converting between different Unicode encodings is fine; either encoding can represent the same range of code points.

Comment: I have way too many calls to `CA2CT` to change them now. But thanks for info.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for expanding upon the answer, I misunderstood what it was saying. I understood that it couldn't be used within the string literal not the variable name.